# Invalid Login Credentials in Oracle APEX After Resetting the Password from the Administration Panel in ADB-S

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I reset one of my administrator user's passwords using the APEX Administration Interface and now he can't login into the workspace, I already tried to reset his password several times with passwords that comply with ADB-S' (Autonomous Database Shared's) Complexity rules but APEX is still throwing an "Invalid Login Credentials" error as if the password, workspace or account name are incorrect. I already reviewed that the three details are to-the-letter, but the error is still showing up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me about 1 hour to figure it out but here's what happens:

Turns out that when an APEX workspace is created, the administrative account is linked with a Database Schema, just as it happens in a normal installation BUT the catch is that APEX Login UI in ADB-S uses "Database Credentials" to login, and if both passwords don't match, the UI will deny the login with the "Invalid credentials error".

The solution to this issue is to change the password using the APEX UI and then change the associated schema password to be the same as the one you entered in the APEX UI, once that's done, in that order, you'll be able to login with your administrator user again.

Comment: hi @Migu, May I know what do you mean by 'APEX UI. You mean 'Administration Services' in web console?

Comment: Hello @chk.buddi , APEX itself contains a tool for managing APEX users, wither in the APEX Administration or in the APEX Workspace Administration. Nothing to do with the cloud console

Comment: I ran into this as well, OCI ADB uses database users so if you create a APEX wksp admin user in the UI with an existing database user, the new UI password won't work. Use the existing schema user login for the database.